# Integrate new relic sdk into a non-gradle project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, newrelic

I am trying to integrate new relic SDK into my app, and the problem is that the code is old and wasn't ported to gradle and we don't have time to port it. So when we try to add the new relic sdk into the project structure as a library is not working and it's throwing me an error that I can't get any feedback, the error is the following.

Failed to detect New Relic instrumentation.  Something likely went wrong during your build process and you should contact support@newrelic.com.

Answer (score 1):

NewRelic provides a video on their page for proper import in ADT/Eclipse. It is available on this page: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-apps/android-installation-and-configuration

Generally, after adding a .jar to your library directory, you must set your build path correctly. Right click on your project, select `Build Path` -> `Configure Build Path` and make sure that the .jar appears in the `Libraries` tab and that it is checked in the `Order and Export` tab.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I am gonna try to import my code to eclipse, although I don't trust eclipse and I prefer using android studio, but looks like there are no option to integrate newRelic sdk into android studio without using gradle.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you prefer not to use gradle for Android Studio?

Comment: I have been working a long time before gradle or even android studio came to the scene of android development, and the continues changes, every new release of the gradle plugin making your code stop building, is something in beta for me, not stable enough and it's adding extra work for developers in something should be really smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Anyways, regarding about the problem of not been able to build in android studio is fixed, but also I were able to import my code to eclipse and make it run and after that I make it work also in android studio without gradle. I have submitted a ticket to new relic just in case they are willing to create a new tutorial for people, like me, that are not using gradle an make it work in android studio.
This is the important line:

-javaagent:/path/to/newrelic-android-3.330.0/lib/class.rewriter.jar

you have to add this into your compilation parameters, and the only way to do it is through the preference of the android studio, instead of your project preference.
Try to find a way to add this command only for when we are building this project and not other ones. Let see.